# How to make a tag appear when you click a checkbox

Tags: html, css

How to make this tag `<h3>` appear when a checkbox is clicked? Right now it is hidden.

```
<h3 class="bark">Bark Bark</h3>
<input type="checkbox" class="title">Hear a dog</input>
```

css:

```
.bark{ 
  visibility: hidden
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked  {
visibility: visible  
}
```

Comment: You can't do it without javascript for a *before* sibling. If `.bark` was **after** the checkbox you could do `:checked + .bark { visibility: visible; }` Since you didn't tag it javascript I didn't answer directly.

Comment: That was my problem.  I wanted it in css only. This explains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Answer (score 10):

```css
.bark{ 
  visibility: hidden
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + h3.bark  {
visibility: visible  
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="title">Hear a dog</input>
<h3 class="bark">Bark Bark</h3>
```

Comment: This repeats the same error the OP had in their question, namely the stray `</input>` in the markup.

Answer (score 4):

Without using scripting language there is one trick:

```css
.bark{ 
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .bark {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="title">Hear a dog</input>
<h3 class="bark">Bark Bark</h3>
```

You should put `h3` after `input`. And use `+` sign to make h3 visible.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52e3psf4/)**

Comment: This repeats the same error the OP had in their question, namely the stray `</input>` in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkInput(cbox) {
      if (cbox.checked) {
          document.getElementById('check_box').style.visibility='visible';
        }
      else{
            document.getElementById('check_box').style.visibility='hidden';
       }
 }
```

```css
#check_box{ 
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="check_box">Bark Bark</h3>
<input type="checkbox" class="title"  onclick="checkInput(this);">Hear a dog
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, you will have to put the checkbox above the h3.
However, if you really want the text "Hear a dog" to appear below the h3, you will have to change a bit more in both the HTML and the CSS.

```css
#checkbark {
  display: none
}
.bark {
  visibility: hidden
}
#checkbark:checked + .bark {
  visibility: visible
}
label[for='checkbark'] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label[for='checkbark']::before {
  content: '\2610  ';
}
#checkbark:checked ~ label[for='checkbark']::before {
  content: '\2611  ';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="title" id="checkbark">
<h3 class="bark">Bark Bark</h3>
<label for="checkbark">Hear a dog</label>
```

This snippet uses the fact that a label for a checkbox does not necessarily have to appear next to the checkbox itself. So we put the checkbox above the h3 and the label below it.
I also added some decoration to the label to make it look like the checkbox is in that location, but that's just cosmetic; you don't have to use it.

Comment: This is the correct answer! BTW love the tick symbol :) I'd also add `user-select: none` to the `label` element, but that's cosmetics.

Comment: This definitely works, but there are way shorter answers that are also correct making this answer obsolete.

Comment: @StigCoder04 That's your opinion. This answer mostly resembles the OP's output (with the h3 above the label).

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<h3 class="bark" id="bark" onclick="showtag()">Bark Bark</h3>
<input type="checkbox" class="title">Hear a dog</input>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script language="javascript">
    function showtag() {
        var showme = document.getelementbyid("bark");
        showme.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <h3 class="bark"><a href="#" id="id1">Bark Bark</a></h3>
<input type="checkbox" class="title">Hear a dog</input>
<script>$('#id1').click(function () {
            if($(".title").is(':checked')){
                $('.title').css('visibility','visible');                    
            }else{
                $('.title').css('visibility','hidden');                                             
            }
        });</script>
```

Please include any jquery min js and try this code :

Comment: How is this supposed to work?  This actually makes the checkbox invisible if you click on the h3.